# Run-time error '6' Overflow while comparing 2 files

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code to compare data between 2 sheets and highlight the differences. But it is giving me a

> Run-time error '6' Overflow

in `compareSheets` procedure while executing the if condition.

Can someone please assist me in fixing the issue?

```
Sub RunCompare()
    'Call the compareSheets routine
    Call compareSheets("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
End Sub


Sub compareSheets(Sheet1 As String, Sheet2 As String)  
    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim mydiffs As Integer

    For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange
        If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
            mycell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            mydiffs = mydiffs + 1
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: See [Integer data type](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3418/data-types-and-limits/11777/integer#t=201705081524166920968) on Documentation.SO. Overflow error means you're busting that limit. Solution is to use a type that can fit the value you're trying to assign it with. How many cells are in `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange`? If it's more than 32,767 an `Integer` will overflow. Tried a `Long`?

Comment: what line is it on the mydiffs increment?  i

Comment: FWIW there are other issues: your `CompareSheets` procedure isn't using its parameters, the parameters are very likely hiding/shadowing the `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` global-scope object variables for these respective worksheets in `ThisWorkbook`, and that comment says absolutely nothing that the code doesn't say already and should be removed. The parameters could be passed `ByVal`, and could be of type `Worksheet` instead of `String`, them being *worksheets* instead of *sheet names* moves that extra responsibility out of the procedure and makes it work beyond `ActiveWorkbook`.

Answer (score 1):

You dim mydiffs as an `integer`, dim it as a `long` instead. What is happening is the number is exceeding 32767.

Also, an issue with your sub (doesn't cause this problem but ought to be corrected) is that you aren't using the parameters Sheet1/2, you are instead using the strings "Sheet1"/"Sheet2", remove the quotation marks as below.

```
Sub compareSheets(Sheet1 As String, Sheet2 As String)  
    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim mydiffs As Long

    For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet2).UsedRange
        If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
            mycell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

        End If
    Next

    MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried making the change suggested above converting integer to Long and removing the quote from sheet anme, still it is throwing the same error( mycell value = nothing ) in below line.     If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then

Comment: Before exploring other options please replace your sub with mine exactly (Copy/paste), it works without issue on my Excel.

Comment: @Karthick what is the value in that cell?

Comment: Thanks I copy/pasted your code as mentioned and still I am getting the same issue. fyi the same piece of code was working fine yesterday not sure what has caused this issue.

Comment: its alphanumeric value.

Comment: @Karthick you're getting an **overflow** error on that `If myCell.Value` statement? Or a different error? Are there any error cells in your data?

Comment: Great the issue has been fixed now, I just scanned through the cells and found some cells having values as #####. I converted the values to numbers and it works fine now. Thanks a lot Mat.